# What's the proper way to exclude this group from my MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, join

Table 1: Users

```
| profile_id | name    |
------------------------
| 1          | Joe     |
| 2          | Jane    |
| 3          | Jill    |
| 4          | Jeffery |
```

Table 2: User and Role to Team Lookup

```
| team_id | profile_id | role   |
---------------------------------
| 1       | 1          | coach  |
| 1       | 2          | player |
| 2       | 4          | coach  |
| 2       | 1          | player |
```

The scenario is that Jill is building a team, and the restriction is that you cannot be a player on more than one team. So I'm trying to build a query that pulls up those eligible to  join Jill's team.

My first attempt was:

```
SELECT `users`.`profile_id`
FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `user_role_to_team_lookup` AS `utr` USING(`profile_id`)
WHERE `utr`.`role` != 'player' OR `utr`.`role` IS NULL
```

The problem is that because Joe is a coach, he matches the criteria~ even though he is also already a player.

What would be the proper way to exclude users that are already players from the result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this without the subquery that most people use:

```
SELECT u.profile_id
FROM users AS u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_role_to_team_lookup AS utr 
  ON u.profile_id = utr.profile_id AND utr.role = 'player'
WHERE utr.profile_id IS NULL
```

In other words, look for a user who is already a player.  Those who aren't a player will match no rows in the outer join, and therefore any column of `utr` will be NULL.

But it's best to put the condition in the `ON` clause of the join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.profile_id
    FROM users u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM user_role_to_team_lookup urtl
                         WHERE urtl.profile_id = u.profile_id
                             AND urtl.role = 'player')
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, researching your answer I was able to learn _why_ the `EXISTS` method is more efficient than the other style `NOT IN` subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this:

```
SELECT profile_id FROM users
WHERE profile_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT profile_id FROM utr WHERE role = 'player');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT profile_id
FROM users
WHERE profile_id NOT IN (
    SELECT profile_id
    FROM user_role_to_team_lookup
    WHERE role = 'player');
```